# Cobol output file not displaying properly

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to output 2 different lines in my cobol program, but it isn't outputting the way I want it to. Instead of writing one of each line it is writing two of the second line.

My code is:

```
DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD INVENT-FILE-IN.
       01 INVENTORY-RECORD-IN.
              05 PART-NUMBER      PIC 9(5).
              05 PART-NAME        PIC X(20).
              05 QUANTITY-ON-HAND PIC 9(3).
              05 UNIT-PRICE       PIC 9V99(6).
              05 RE-ORDER-POINT   PIC 9(3).
              05 SUPPLIER-ID      PIC X(2).
   FD INVENT-REPORT-OUT.
       01 INVENTORY-RECORD-OUT.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
              05 PART-NUMBER      PIC 9(5). 
              05 FILLER           PIC X(3) VALUE SPACES.
              05 PART-NAME        PIC X(20).
              05 FILLER           PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
              05 QUANTITY-ON-HAND PIC 9(4).
              05 FILLER           PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
              05 UNIT-PRICE       PIC 9V99(6).
              05 FILLER           PIC X(2).
              05 INVENTORY-VALUE  PIC 9V99(10).
       01 INVENTORY-RECORD-HDR-LN1.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(9)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(20) VALUE "INVENTORY REPORT FOR".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 CURRENT-MONTH    PIC 9(2).
              05 FILLER           PIC X(18) VALUE SPACES.
       01 INVENTORY-RECORD-HDR-LN2.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(1)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(7)  VALUE "PART NO".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(1)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(9)  VALUE "PART NAME".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(13) VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(2)  VALUE "OH".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(5)  VALUE "PRICE".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(6)  VALUE SPACES.
              05 FILLER           PIC X(5)  VALUE "VALUE".
              05 FILLER           PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
       01 INVENTORY-RECORD-END.
              05 TOTAL-VALUE      PIC 9(7)V99.
              05 NUM-RECORDS-IN   PIC 9(3).
              05 NUM-RECORDS-OUT  PIC 9(3).
   FD RE-ORDER-FILE.
       01 REORDER-RECORD-OUT.
              05 PART-NUMBER      PIC 9(5).
              05 PART-NAME        PIC X(20).
              05 QUANTITY-ON-HAND PIC 9(3).
              05 SUPPLIER-ID      PIC X(2).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   OPEN-RTN.
   OPEN INPUT  INVENT-FILE-IN.
   OPEN OUTPUT INVENT-REPORT-OUT.
   OPEN OUTPUT RE-ORDER-FILE.
   PERFORM HEADER1-RTN.

   HEADER1-RTN.
   MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE(5:2) TO CURRENT-MONTH.
   WRITE INVENTORY-RECORD-HDR-LN1.
   PERFORM HEADER2-RTN.

   HEADER2-RTN.
   WRITE INVENTORY-RECORD-HDR-LN2
   END-WRITE.
   PERFORM CLOSE-RTN.

   CLOSE-RTN.
   CLOSE INVENT-FILE-IN.
   CLOSE INVENT-REPORT-OUT.
   CLOSE RE-ORDER-FILE.
   STOP RUN.
```

The output file turns out like this:

```
 PART NO PART NAME             O11 PRICE      VALUE
 PART NO PART NAME             O11 PRICE      VALUE
```

But I want it to turn out like this:

```
         INVENTORY REPORT FOR   11
 PART NO PART NAME             OH PRICE      VALUE
```

These are just the headers for the rest of the data, and I can't figure out how to get them both to display properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: VALUE clauses should not have any affect in the FILE SECTION. Put your titles/headings in WORKING-STORAGE and MOVE to the output area and WRITE, or use WRITE ... FROM ... to do the same thing.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using micro focus visual cobol for eclipse

Comment: @BillWoodger It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it is working. Did you not get any diagnostic messages or markers in your IDE about what should have been identified by the compiler? On the other hand, it seemed to have been "working" to an extent, with the VALUEs for the first 01 causing the output to appear as it did. That surprised me, I've not known that to happen before :-)

Comment: I didn't get any messages like that. It was definitely weird how it was displaying.